# How to permanently disable firewall in Red Hat Linux

Tags: firewall, iptables, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have followed the below steps to disable the firewall in Linux. After reboot, again firewall is enabled. How to disable firewall permanently?

1. Login as the root user.
2. Next enter the following three commands to disable firewall.

   ```
   service iptables save  
   service iptables stop  
   chkconfig iptables off
   ```
3. Disable IPv6 firewall.

   ```
   service ip6tables save  
   service ip6tables stop  
   chkconfig ip6tables off
   ```

Answer (score 9):

For version 7 of CentOS or RedHat Enterprise you must use the command systemctl.

For example:

```
#Check status:

systemctl status firewalld

#Stop firewall:

systemctl stop firewalld

#Disable firewall:

systemctl disable firewalld
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/12/linux-deshabilitar-firewall-redhat-centos.html

Answer (score 3):

FYI: This no longer works in RHEL7, and the handy init.d script has been removed.

The following worked for me.

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, the old way of doing it doesn't work in rhel 7.2

Answer (score 1):

For disabling it permanently you can remove the iptables file from the directory /etc/rc.d/init.d.

Comment: This would only work on distros which use init and not on system which use systemd or upstart.

Answer (score 0):

You can permanently disable firewall by running iptables -F command every time you restart your linux host.

Just run below commands 
cd /etc/profile.d/
touch custom.sh
echo "iptables -F" >>custom.sh

create custom.sh file and write your command(iptables -F) inside that file

So every time you restart your Linux host iptables -F will be executed and your firewall will be disabled.
It worked for me.

Comment: That does not disable the firewall, it merely flushes all of the rules. Rules can still be added by other applications after you flush them. A prime example would be Docker containers and the associated chains.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @teknopaul answer and it worked fine both iptables and firewalld are stopped and inactive, however, if after reboot you still see some rules on running command `iptables -L` than check for your network interfaces by command `ifconfig`. If you see network interface `virbr0` then disable it using commands

```
systemctl stop libvirtd.service
systemctl disable libvirtd.service
```

Now when you `reboot` the machine and run `iptables -L` you will see no rules and if you run `ifconfig` you will not see `virbr0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a single command with:
`sudo systemctl disable --now firewalld`